# How to adjust the width of the line in the function "geom_xspline" function of ggalt package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was smoothing the line of my graph with "geom_xspline", it works quite well, but the problem is that you can't adjust the width of the line.
[image: I want the widest line]

Attached is the data :

```
AÑO <- seq(2005,2024, by = 1)
PIA_increase <- c(-30501,24337, -23296,12718,314,  14499,  86065, -54206,66258,  20795,  20901, 107653,
                          -8149 , 91357 ,  152 ,-58815  , 0, 229997,    378 ,204403
                          ) 
Congreso_1 <- data.frame(AÑO, PIA_increase)

library(ggalt)

ggplot(Congreso_1, aes(AÑO,PIA_increase))+
  geom_point(color = "red")+
  geom_xspline(position = "identity",spline_shape=-0.4, color = "red", size = 1)+ aes(lwd = 2)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

I have tried adding the function "aes(lwd = 2)" but the line becomes too thick and cannot be adjusted.

[image]

I would like to be able to adjust the line between 1 to 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `ggalt` does not account for the `linewidth` aesthetic introduced in `ggplot2 3.4.0`. The same issue was already filed on [GH](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt/issues/84).

Using `+ aes(lwd = 2)` is a work-around to "fix" the issue, but you also have to set the scale for `linewidth` using `scale_linewidth_identity`. Otherwise the default scale for line width is applied.

```r
library(ggalt)

ggplot(Congreso_1, aes(AÑO, PIA_increase)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  geom_xspline(
    position = "identity", 
    spline_shape = -0.4,
    color = "blue"
  ) +
  aes(lwd = 2) +
  scale_linewidth_identity() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
```

[image]

And as a reference here is the plot with the default scale applied:

```r
ggplot(Congreso_1, aes(AÑO, PIA_increase)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  geom_xspline(
    position = "identity", 
    spline_shape = -0.4,
    color = "blue"
  ) +
  aes(lwd = 2) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried it and it works great.